# Error al mostrar datos en la vista de angular

Tags: php, angular, http-get

Tengo un error al obtener los datos en mi vista angular les agradezco mucho de antemano..eh pasado ayer y hoy buscando soluciones pero no lo he logrado..el error que me sale en la consola del navegador es este:

ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
Angular 7
Este error me aparece 3 veces
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero los datos si me los esta obteniendo, hice un console y me muestra los datos en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto mi codigo angular y php :
modelo categoria:

```
export class Categoria {
id: number;
nombre: string;
imagen: string;

constructor(id: number, nombre: string, imagen: string) {
    this.id = id
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.imagen = imagen;
}
```

}

el servicio para obtener los datos:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatosService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  obtenerRopa(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost/catalogo/backend/obtener_ropa.php');
  }

}
```

el componente.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Categoria } from '../models/categoria.models';
import { DatosService } from '../services/datos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-catalogo-hombre',
  templateUrl: './catalogo-hombre.component.html',
  styleUrl: './catalogo-hombre.component.css'
})
export class CatalogoHombreComponent implements OnInit {
    ropas: Categoria[] = [];

    constructor(private datosService: DatosService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.obtenerRopa();
    }

    obtenerRopa(): void {
        this.datosService.obtenerRopa().subscribe(
            (data: Categoria[]) => { 
            
                this.ropas = data;
                console.log(this.ropas);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

la vista de mi componente

```
<div class="main-content">
<h2 class="main-content__title">Catálogo de Hombre </h2>
<div class="main-content__tarjetas">  
    <div *ngFor="let ropa of ropas">

        <div>ID: {{ ropa.id }}</div>
        <div>Nombre: {{ ropa.nombre }}</div>
        <img src="{{ropa.imagen}}">
      </div>
      
</div>
```

mi archivo php para obtener los datos de la tabla:

```
<?php
include('./cors.php');
require('./conexion.php');


$rpta = array(
    'status' => 'ERROR',
    'message' => 'Error desconocido'
);

try {
    $conn = dameConexion();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ropa`";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $rpta = array(
        'status' => 'OK',
        'message' => 'Se obtuvieron los datos correctamente',
        'datos' => $rows
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {

$rpta['error'] = $e->getMessage();

}
```

echo json_encode($rpta);
?>

Answer (score 1):

Tenes un error al tratar de asignarle el valor a la variable `ropas` dentro del componente `CatalogoHombreComponent`, porque le estas asignando la del cuerpo de la respuesta (que es un objeto, por lo tanto no lo podes iterar en el bucle con el *ngFor) a tu variable local, la asigación debería ser:

```
obtenerRopa(): void {
        this.datosService.obtenerRopa().subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.ropas = data.datos;
                console.log(this.ropas);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
```

Cuando haces el subscribe a tu llamada http, tu API devuelve un objeto de este tipo:

```
interface CategoriaResponse {
status: string,
message: string,
datos: Categoria[]
}
```

(Ejemplo de tipado)

Podes parametrizar tu respuesta desde el service agregando el tipado correspondiente:

`return this.http.get<CategoriaResponse>('http://localhost/catalogo/backend/obtener_ropa.php');`